# CSS box-shadow on divs over image/video background impossible?

Tags: background, css

I'm having a superbgimage/jw player background on my website in progress. When I apply a CSS box-shadow on the content divs above the background, the shadow does not mix (does not darken) with the background. It looks like a grey halo. Do box-shadows only work on white backgrounds?

Halo instead of shadow mixing with background image (darkening it)

[image: Halo instead of shadow mixing with background image]

CSS for superbgimage background and jQuery Isotope plugin divs

```
#background {
    background: inherit;
    }

#superbgimage {
    display: none;
    }

.item {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    }
```

Divs for background

```
<fieldset id="background">
    <a href="media/background_0.jpg"></a>
    <a href="media/background_1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="media/background_2.jpg"></a>
    ...
</fieldset>

<div id="superbgimage"></div>
```

Script for background

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$.fn.superbgimage.options = {
    preload: 1,
    randomtransition: 0,
    slideshow: 1,
    slide_interval: 9000,
    randomimage: 1,
    speed: 3000,
    transition: 1
};

$('#background').superbgimage().hide();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Its possible you are not setting the correct attributes for the box shadow.  Please post/jsFiddle your CSS and HTML so we can trouble shoot.

Comment: @Lokase Thanks, I put some more details in the edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using a cross-browser solution like this:

```
.shadow {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RGBA colors instead of HEX.  RGBA will allow you to set an opacity for the color allowing the background to bleed through.

Example:

```
rgba(0,0,255,0.5)
```

On a side note, try using an online generator for CSS3 elements like box-shadow, it will take the guess work out of creating these more complex elements:

http://css3generator.com/

Comment: Cheers, that's a useful hint, too.