# Darken background image on hover

Tags: html, css

How would I darken a **background image** on hover **without** making a new darker image?

CSS:

```
.image {
  background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/round-simple-social-icons/58/facebook.png');
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
}
```

JSFiddle link: [**http://jsfiddle.net/qrmqM/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/qrmqM/1/)

Comment: check this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396753/css-box-shadow-on-divs-over-image-video-background-impossible

Answer (score 54, accepted):

How about this, using an overlay?

```
.image:hover > .overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    border-radius:30px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6bjTQ/)**

Comment: Do you have an idea for images that are not a regular shape?. I have some pentagon icons that i want to animate on click, so you can have that "pressing a button feel". i wonder if i should make another img for each of the icons, or maybe i could make it do with one transparent.

Answer (score 95):

Similar, but again a little bit different.

Make the image 100% opacity so it is clear.
And then on img hover reduce it to the opacity you want. In this example, I have also added easing for a nice transition.

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

Thank you Robert Byers for your **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmL1tsjh/)**

Comment: This is the only answer that works for any shape image. Some of the other answers have tricks that will work if your image is rectangular or circular. But this works perfectly for any shape. This answer just lacks a fiddle. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/cmL1tsjh/

Comment: Works like a charm! Only thing I'd suggest changing is that move all the transitions to the `img`, as the easing cuts when you move your cursor off from the image.

Comment: Note that this won't work on IE11 if you have the misfortune of having to support that.

Answer (score 29):

I was able to achieve this more easily than the above answers and in a single line of code by using the new [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) CSS option.

It's [compatibility in modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) is pretty good - 95% at time of writing, though less than the other answers.

```css
img:hover{
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/300'>
```

Comment: filter option is amazing

Comment: I like this one. It seems to work better than using opacity.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to darken the image, use an overlay element with `rgba` and `opacity` properties which will darken your image...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XLEGK/)

```
<div><span></span></div>

div {
    background-image: url(http://im.tech2.in.com/gallery/2012/dec/stockimage_070930177527_640x360.jpg);
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}

div span {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}

div:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Note: Am also using CSS3 transitions for smooth dark effect

---

If anyone one to save an extra element in the DOM than you can use `:before` or `:after` pseudo as well..

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/XLEGK/18/)

```
div {
    background-image: url(http://im.tech2.in.com/gallery/2012/dec/stockimage_070930177527_640x360.jpg);
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}

div:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

---

#### Using some content over the darkened overlay of the image

Here am using CSS Positioning techniques with `z-index` to overlay content over the darkened `div` element.
[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/XLEGK/19/)

```
div {
    background-image: url(http://im.tech2.in.com/gallery/2012/dec/stockimage_070930177527_640x360.jpg);
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

div:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

div:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

div p {
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity):

```
.image {
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/round-simple-social-icons/58/facebook.png');
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    opacity:0.5;
}

.image:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrmqM/5/)

Comment: What if I want to keep the original opacity and make it darker when hovered over?

Comment: Then you can use another image, which is darker , or put a parent container and then darken that container ( not the image ) .

Answer (score 6):

you can use this:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
```

as seen on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24084708/8953378

Comment: This is nice when you just want to darken the color but don't know the color yet and can't change opacity for other reasons

Comment: This is a very nice solution that has great browser support and is imo better than using  transform or an overlay.
Works on all browsers AND automatically has the correct border-radius and is **color agnostic** which is excellent!!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a "shade" class that you can add directly to any `<img>` tag like so

```
<img src="imgs/myimg.png" class="shade">
```

```css
img.shade:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(85%);
    -webkit-transition: all 10ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 10ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 10ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 10ms ease;
    transition: all 10ms ease;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add css:

```
.image{
    opacity:.5;
}

.image:hover{
    // CSS properties
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: How about without making a new image?

Answer (score 2):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/qrmqM/6/

CSS

```
.image {
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/round-simple-social-icons/58/facebook.png');
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
      opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.image:hover{
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/round-simple-social-icons/58/facebook.png');
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;

    border-radius:100px;
  opacity:1;
            filter:alpha(opacity=100);

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
.image {
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/round-simple-social-icons/58/facebook.png');
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    opacity:0.2;
}

.image:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.image:hover {
   background: #000;
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    border-radius:60px;

}
```

You will get darken

Comment: How about without making a new image?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it without adding an extra overlay element, or using two images, is to use the :before or :after selector.

```
.image {
    position: relative;
}
.image:hover:after {
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
```

This will not work in older browsers of course; just say it degrades gracefully!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use the current image and get a darker image then you need to create a new one. Else you can simply reduce the opacity of the .image class and the in the .image:hover you can put a higher value for opacity. But then the image without hover would look pale.

The best way would be to create two images and add the following :

```
.image {
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/round-simple-social-icons/58/facebook.png');
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    opacity:0.9;   
}
.image:hover{
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/round-simple-social-icons/58/facebook_hover.png');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a div around the image and make the image change in opacity on hover and add an inset box shadow to the div on hover.

```
img:hover{
    opacity:.5;
}
.image:hover{
    box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 100px 100px #000;
}

<div class="image"><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just try this code.

```
img:hover
{
    box-shadow: 0 25px 50px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) inset; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 25px 50px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) inset; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 25px 50px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) inset; 
    -o-box-shadow: 0 25px 50px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) inset;
}
```